# why does this program create a zombie process and how do I fix it?

Tags: c, linux, zombie-process

My question is I can't undertand why those code still generate zombie process. how can I fixed it? thanks.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>


int count = 0;

/**
 * signal  callback
 * @param signo
 */
void sigcallback(int signo) {
    short stime = 5;
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    while (1) {

        printf("wake up,%d\n", getpid());
        sleep((stime + 1) - (short) (time(NULL) % stime));

    }
}

int call_cmd(void) {
    count++;

    int i;
    pid_t pid;
    signal(SIGCHLD, sigcallback);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            printf("error with fork\n");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG);
        } else {
            printf("\t\t\tsid is %d,count is %d,pid is %d\n", getsid(getpid()), count, getpid());
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void notice_root(int signo) {
    printf("execut root signal\n");
    waitpid(0, NULL, 0);
}

int main(void) {
    pid_t pid;

    int i;
    signal(SIGCHLD, notice_root);
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            printf("error with fork\n");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            exit(0);
        } else {
            setsid();
            call_cmd();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your parent pid, called from main() is simply exiting, meaning that the child it forked off will have no parent and therefore cannot get reaped when it exits.

Comment: @grijesh: only in the call_cmd() fucntion. there's a fork in main() which ISN'T being waited on.

Comment: @MarcB yes you are correct I notice precisely again after your comment .

Comment: It's not safe to call `printf()` from a signal handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite sleep loop in your signal handler `sigcallback`. Once a signal has been handled by that function, the process will never handle another `SIGCHLD` signal again, since the signal handler never returns. This is likely the cause of your zombies.

You do not get one signal delivered for every exited child. If two children exit "simultaneously", you will only get a single `SIGCHLD` delivered. So, when you wait in your signal handler (either of them), you should wait in a loop to reap all the children that have exited. Something along the lines of:

```
for (;;) {
    pid_t p = waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG);
    if (p <= 0) break;
    /* ... */
}
```

When your process exits, the children of that process will be inherited by the init process, so they will be reaped properly. However, your infinite loop prevented 3 things:

- It would not reap simultaneously exited children.
- It would not reap any more children after reaping the first.
- It would not allow the process to exit, so the children could not be reaped by the init process.

Comment: hi,your explanation is very clear.thanks a lot. one more thing, we should do "exit" at the first-level child. zombie processes are all gone. I think that because when we in the infinite loop. the parent  `waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG);` will never execute.

Comment: @9nix00: Correct. As I mentioned, the infinite loop prevents your process from being able to exit. Your code would only work if the parent process managed to execute the `waitpid()` line, have it return `0` (meaning child is not dead), and parent die before the child dies.